# Angular 2 Form Validation Error "Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!"

Tags: html, forms, validation, angular

App.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Form Validation</h2>
  <form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="prettyName">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prettyName" required minlength="4" maxlength="20" [(ngModel)]="prettyName" name="prettyName" #name="ngModel">
  <div *ngIf="name.errors && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div [hidden]="!name.errors.required">
      Name is required
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!name.errors.minlength">
      Name must be at least 4 characters long
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!name.errors.maxlength">
      Name cannot be more than 20 characters long
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
// ... (Same things for username, email and password)
```

App.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 prettyName: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

I have followed the official documentation about form validation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#template1

Does anyone know where this error is coming from please?

Cheers

Comment: `name.error` This cant be accessed as `name` is a string. Change the input/form id from `name` to anything else

Comment: Changing the id of my input form has not resolve the error, you meant:

<input type="text" id="prettyName etc...> ?

Comment: You changed both? You should change one of them

Comment: How did you declare `prettyName` in your class?

Comment: I have declared prettyName as a string (app.component.ts).

Anyway, it is working now, going to update the code

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should either change your component variable, or your template `#name` variable. They are colliding:

```
export class AppComponent {
  prettyname: string; // here
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

Also change your `String` to `string`

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="prettyName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prettyName" required minlength="4" maxlength="20" [(ngModel)]="prettyName" name="prettyName" #name="ngModel">
    <div *ngIf="name.errors && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div [hidden]="!name.errors.required">
        Name is required
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!name.errors.minlength">
        Name must be at least 4 characters long
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!name.errors.maxlength">
        Name cannot be more than 20 characters long
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have changed the code as you told me, didn't resolve the error though.

Can you just check if I have done what you meant please?

Comment: You've changed too much.. Ill update my answer. You should not have changed the `#name` and the template variables addressing this variable

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when you try to define a template reference variable with the same name of an existing variable, like for example in this case:

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'example',
    template: `
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" #name="ngModel" >
       `
    })
   export class AppComponent {
     name:string;

 }
```

As you can see, there’s the template reference variable #name on the input and there’s also a variable called name on my class, this will cause the following error when you try to run the application:

```
   zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot assign to a 
   reference or variable! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: 
   Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!(…) Error: Cannot 
   assign to a reference or variable!
```

> the solution is to change the name of one of your variables.

Answer (score 4):

I had that error with a `[(ngModel)]` inside a `*ngFor` :

```
<div *ngFor="let condition of rule.conditions; let i = index" class="condition">    
        <condition [(condition)]="condition" ...
```

I had to do this :

```
<div *ngFor="let condition of rule.conditions; let i = index" class="condition">    
        <condition [(condition)]="rule.conditions[i]" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can popup with different causes. The one I found involves the use of `ngFor`. In particular, when binding `ngModel` to the iteration variable:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <input [(ngModel)]="item" />
</div>
```

This kind of pattern will trigger the same cryptic error.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Angular 6 Forms**

encountered this error "*ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!*"

To resolve this issue I **changed this HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Username" required #username="ngModel"/>
<div [hidden]="username.valid || username.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
  Name is required
</div>
```

**To this**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Username" required #usernameMsg="ngModel"/>
<div [hidden]="usernameMsg.valid || usernameMsg.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
  Name is required
</div>
```

reference name and model name were same

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the use of the template var declaration pattern with *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="10; let numVar">{{numVar}}</div>
```

It seems to be forbidden in production mode